# Binding with ElementName in Style setter

Tags: wpf

I have a base style for Button which contains the ControlTemplate, then I want to create a few styles based on that which just set the Content for commonly used things like "OK", "Cancel", etc.

In those styles I have an image followed by some text, and I want to bind the height of the image to the height of the text, so I've got the following:

```
<Style x:Key="OkayButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource RoundedButtonStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{DynamicResource OkayIcon}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=ButtonText}"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="ButtonText" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,0,0,0" Text="Okay"/>
            </Grid>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Doing that gives me the error:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=ButtonText'. BindingExpression:Path=ActualHeight; DataItem=null; target element is 'Image' (Name=''); target property is 'Height' (type 'Double')
```

I'm guessing it's trying to find ButtonText in the ControlTemplate which it obviously can't.  Is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do here and bind to another element's property from within this style setter?

Comment: Not sure, but you're going to run into a second problem once you get this working: There'll only ever be one instance of that grid. If you have multiple OkayButtons, only the last-created one will get content. To fix that the Content has to be a separate resource with its own key, with the `x:Shared="False"` attribute.

Comment: I would expect it to work, weird. Did you try using a binding like: "{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}, Path=Children[1].ActualHeight}" just in case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why that binding is not working for you; perhaps because name resolution visual tree something or other.

But this works for me, and also addresses the shared-resource issue I mentioned in comments.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ButtonContent" >
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Image 
            Grid.Column="0" 
            Source="{DynamicResource OkayIcon}" 
            Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=ButtonText}"
            />

        <TextBlock 
            x:Name="ButtonText" 
            Grid.Column="1" 
            Margin="5,0,0,0" 
            Text="Okay" 
            FontSize="32"
            />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

<Style 
    x:Key="OkayButtonStyle" 
    TargetType="{x:Type Button}" 
    BasedOn="{StaticResource RoundedButtonStyle}"
    >
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ButtonContent}" />
</Style>
```